# Probability that a restaurant is better than another

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Consider two restaurants $A$ and $B$ that both have a set of online reviews $S_A$ and $S_B$, and each review can have an integer score from 1 to 5. What is the probability that a new review for $B$, $r_B$, will have a higher score than a new review for $A$, $r_A$?

I tried to solve this problem by considering the distribution of reviews for each restaurant, that is
$$P(r_B > r_A) = \sum_{i=1}^{5}P(r_A = i)P(r_B > i)$$
Where $P(r_A = i)$ would be the fraction of $S_A$ that is equal to $i$ and $P(r_B > i)$ the fraction of $S_B$ that is bigger than $i$.

However, I've noticed that this is only useful if the number of reviews for both $A$ and $B$ is sufficiently big. That's because if $A$ had 1000 reviews and an average score of 4.8 and $B$ had 1 review with a score of 5, then $B$, by the above equation, would be considered the best option, even though it has only 1 review. That means there is some uncertainty associated to the distribution of reviews. In this sense, how does one take this uncertainty into account?

Comment: If you believe in your probability distribution for reviews, then you can get an answer you believe for your question. But, you haven't set any criteria for deciding if you believe in the distribution.  Just one review would seem to be extremely weak evidence for deciding the distribution.  There is no absolute way to set these criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_A(s)$ and $P_B(s)$ be [categorical distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution#) over $\{1,...,5\}$.

Then we can model this using a Bayesian approach, which will automatically take into account sample size.

The conjugate prior of a categorical distribution is the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) over the $4-$simplex. You can choose the uniform Dirichlet, where the concentration parameter $\alpha$ is $(1,1,1,1,1)$ to avoid any biasing (unless you have a reason to think we should favor a particular score for that restaurant a priori).

With this in place, we can calculate the [poster predictive distribution of a new survey from each restaurant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution#Posterior_predictive_distribution). Since we used a conjugate prior, the posterior predictive distribution has a nice form:

$$P(r_X = i|\mathbf{c},\alpha) = \frac{c_i+\alpha_i}{N + \sum_{i=1}^5 \alpha_i}$$

Where $c_i$ is the number of reviews for restaurant $X$ with score of $i$. N is just the total number of reviews.

Assuming we use the uniform prior $\alpha = (1,1,1,1,1)$ then this simplifies to:

$$P(r_X = i|\mathbf{c},\alpha) = \frac{c_i+1}{N + 5}$$

This means that if we have 1000 observations of $A$ and only $5$ of $B$ then the predictive distribution of $A$ will be driven almost entirely by the data whereas for $B$ it will still be influenced by the prior "flat" distribution, which will avoid the extreme noise of small sample sizes.

You can then use the posterior predictive distributions for $A$ and $B$ to do your analysis as you laid out in your post.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Would it be better to use a prior that reflects the average new restaurant instead of an uniform one?

Comment: @WordP if you can get that then yes — suspect it won’t be uniform :)